# WSDL generated in WCF consumed by Delphi client

Tags: wcf, delphi

I have a WCF (.net 3.5) service that implements security through ws-security. I have generated a WSDL file for consumption by a client created in Delhi v7.0.  I have been having a number of issues with the SOAP message that is received from the Delhi client:

1) The SOAP message is different from the SOAP message generated by a .NET web form using the same WSDL file. for eg. SOAP message sent by Delhi client doesn't contain `<Header>` element

2) The `<Body>` element is missing from the SOAP message. etc.

In summary the integration has not been smooth. I see this as some incompatibility issue. I want to understand how to resolve such issues. What precautions should be taken so that any client using the same WSDL can send SOAP message which is similar to the SOAP message sent by .NET client.

Comment: Since you mention ws-security, I assume you are using `wsHttpBinding`?

Comment: The problem isn't the WSDL of the WCF service, it's how the Delphi proxy generator is interpreting it. If the service methods are using simple data types, it may be easier to wrap a .NET based client as a COM interop object for the Delphi app to consume than trying to figuring out how tweak the Delphi proxy code to generate the soap format the WCF service is expecting.

Comment: @rally25rs: wsHttpBinding is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the  tags by using a stringreplace on the XML string right before it goes out the door "onto the wire".  You need a RIO_BeforeExecute handler, and you can then deal with the SOAPRequest directly.

Comment: I found some information related to incompatibility in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101578/how-to-consume-non-iis-hosted-wcf-c-web-service-from-delphi-2007. Is it true?

Comment: Each generation of Delphi seems to get better.  D7 is really old.  I'm using the DelphiXE SOAP libraries with D2005, which helps a lot. But we still have to do some tweaking.