# can not add wcf service to delphi

Tags: c#, wcf, delphi, soap, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi SOAP Envelope and WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473051/delphi-soap-envelope-and-wcf)

I have made a self hosted WCF application on C#. Binding method is `BasicHttpBinding (SOAP)`. Then I made client C# application that consumes the service, I added service reference with Visual Studio with no errors at all. Till here everything is fine.
Problem occurs when I try to connect a Delphi 7 client. Here are steps I did:

> 1. Created a new Application
> 2. Dropped HTTPRIO component on the form
> 3. With WSDL Importer Wizard imported service
> 4. step 3 created a file, I named it as FRS.pas and saved.
> 5. Added FRS to main applications "uses"
> 6. Run application and get error message saying "[Error] FRS.pas(52): Undeclared identifier: 'GetOptions'" And "[Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(7): Could not compile used unit 'FRS.pas'"

Here is generated code

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from the
// WSDL File described below:
// WSDL     : http://localhost:933/FRS?wsdl
// Encoding : utf-8
// Version  : 1.0
// (29.11.2012 13:16:07 - 1.33.2.5)
// ************************************************************************ //

unit FRS;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were                 referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Borland types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:GetOptions      - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:GetOptionsResponse - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:SetOptions      - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:SetOptionsResponse - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:Beep            - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:BeepResponse    - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:GetStatus       - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:GetStatusResponse - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:RegisterReceipt - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:RegisterReceiptResponse - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:RegisterBill    - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:RegisterBillResponse - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:PrintReport     - "http://tempuri.org/"
  // !:PrintReportResponse - "http://tempuri.org/"


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // soapAction: http://tempuri.org/IFRS/%operationName%
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // binding   : BasicHttpBinding_IFRS
  // service   : FRS
  // port      : BasicHttpBinding_IFRS
  // URL       : http://localhost:933/FRS/soap
  // ************************************************************************ //
  IFRS = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{75F3494A-C58E-25D0-475B-CD49AEDABE03}']
    function  GetOptions(const parameters: GetOptions): GetOptionsResponse; stdcall;
    function  SetOptions(const parameters: SetOptions): SetOptionsResponse; stdcall;
    function  Beep(const parameters: Beep): BeepResponse; stdcall;
    function  GetStatus(const parameters: GetStatus): GetStatusResponse; stdcall;
    function  RegisterReceipt(const parameters: RegisterReceipt):     RegisterReceiptResponse; stdcall;
    function  RegisterBill(const parameters: RegisterBill): RegisterBillResponse; stdcall;
    function  PrintReport(const parameters: PrintReport): PrintReportResponse; stdcall;
  end;

function GetIFRS(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO =     nil): IFRS;


implementation

function GetIFRS(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): IFRS;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://localhost:933/FRS?wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://localhost:933/FRS/soap';
  defSvc  = 'FRS';
  defPrt  = 'BasicHttpBinding_IFRS';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as IFRS);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IFRS), 'http://tempuri.org/', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(IFRS),     'http://tempuri.org/IFRS/%operationName%');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(IFRS), ioLiteral);

end.
```

And Here is c# service interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFRS
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetOptions();

    [OperationContract]
    void SetOptions(string xml);

    [OperationContract]
    void Beep();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetStatus();

    [OperationContract]
    void RegisterReceipt(string xml);

    [OperationContract]
    void RegisterBill(string xml);

    [OperationContract]
    void PrintReport(string xml);
}
```

As I can understand there is some compatibility issues, cause c# client works fine.
I am not good at Delphi, but I must give a working sample.
If anyone has faced this kind of problem, please help.

Comment: As the top of the generated .pas file says the Delphi 7 WDSL importer does not recognize the GetOptions etc. types in the WSDL.
This may have to do with the 'style' and 'use' of the WSDL - see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/.
I do not know which types the importer for Delphi 7 recognizes, but I suggest you search in that direction. What WSDL style does your C# define, and can Delphi7 consume that?

Comment: Your SOAP version itself may also be a reason, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101578/how-to-consume-non-iis-hosted-wcf-c-sharp-web-service-from-delphi-2007?rq=1

Comment: @JanDoggen you were right, C# by default uses `Document/Literal/Wrapped` SOAP format and Delphi expects `RPC/Encoded` format. Solved my problem by adding just one attribute on service interface `[XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use = OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473051/delphi-soap-envelope-and-wcf) is detailed answer on this issue. **Thanks for your help**